# Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" al crear una DB

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo muchas dudas con respecto a los caminos que debo tomar al momento de crear una BBDD con *MySQL*. Debo  asociar las *Foreing key* a las tablas, el error que muestra es el siguiente:

> #1005 - No puedo crear tabla parcial. Actúa (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Mas que nada necesito una orientación para saber si voy por el camino correcto en base al problema del parcial que tengo.

```
CREATE TABLE OBRA (
    ID INT (10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    TITULO TEXT (30) NOT NULL,
    FECHA_CREACION DATE,
    TITULO_LIBRE TEXT (30) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE TEATRO(
    ID INT (10) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE TEXT (30) NOT NULL,
    CAPACIDAD INT (10) NOT NULL,
    TELEFONO INT (10),
    FAX VARCHAR (30),
    LOCALIDAD TEXT (30) NOT NULL,
    VALOR_ENTRADA INT (10) NOT NULL,
    COD_POSTAL INT (10) NOT NULL
    );
    
 CREATE TABLE ACTUA(
     ID_OBRA INT (10) NOT NULL,
     CUIL_ACTOR INT (10) NOT NULL,
     ID_ROL INT (10) NOT NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY (ID_OBRA) REFERENCES OBRA(ID),
     FOREIGN KEY (CUIL_ACTOR) REFERENCES ACTOR (CUIL),
     FOREIGN KEY (ID_ROL) REFERENCES ROL(ID)
     );
     
 CREATE TABLE PRESENTACION(
     ID_OBRA INT (10) NOT NULL,
     ID_TEATRO INT (10) NOT NULL,
     BUTACAS_OCUPADAS INT (30) NOT NULL,
     FOREIGN KEY (ID_OBRA) REFERENCES OBRA(ID),
     FOREIGN KEY (ID_TEATRO) REFERENCES TEATRO(ID)
     );
     
 CREATE TABLE ACTOR(
     CUIL INT (10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     APELLIDO TEXT (30) NOT NULL,
     NOMBRE TEXT (30) NOT NULL,
     NOMBRE_ARTISTICO TEXT (30) NOT NULL,
     FOTO VARCHAR,
     SEXO TEXT
    );
CREATE TABLE ROL (
    ID INT (10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    DESCRIPCION TEXT NOT NULL,
    PORCENTAJE INT NOT NULL
);
```

**[image: modelo E-R]**

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a SOes. ¿A qué te refieres con acoplar mediante FK 2 BBDD? Qué intentaste puntualmente y por qué dices que falló? Qué error sale? Ve a [edit] y añade esta información

Comment: Perdon, me referi mal, seria asociar las Foreing key a las tablas, el error que larga es el siguiente: #1005 - No puedo crear tabla `parcial`.`actua` (Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: Edita la pregunta como te indiqué, por favor :)

Comment: Perfecto, ya esta editado. Agradecería cualquier ayuda. Saludos

Comment: Prueba creando primero las tablas sin FK y luego las tablas que tienen FK.

Comment: Es lo que fui haciendo, me deje copiado toda la sintaxis DDL en un bloc de notas como para tener un respaldo, luego fui ejecutando la sintaxis de las tablas sin FK, y por ultimo cuando empece a ejecutar las tablas que tienen FK es donde viene el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Varias cosas:

- Quítale los NOT NULL a los campos "locales" que usas en los FK.
- Procura darle nombre a tus constraints.

Por ejemplo, la tabla ACTUA sería:

```
CREATE TABLE ACTUA(
     ID_OBRA INT (10),
     CUIL_ACTOR INT (10),
     ID_ROL INT (10),
     CONSTRAINT fk_actua_obra FOREIGN KEY (ID_OBRA) REFERENCES OBRA(ID),
     CONSTRAINT fk_actua_actor FOREIGN KEY (CUIL_ACTOR) REFERENCES ACTOR (CUIL),
     CONSTRAINT fk_actua_rol FOREIGN KEY (ID_ROL) REFERENCES ROL(ID)
     );
```

Ayúdate con `show engine innodb status` o `show warnings` para que te muestre con detalle en qué falló la creación de la FK. Va a salir algo como

```
show warnings
--------------

+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning |  121 | Create or Alter table `test`.`t2` with foreign key constraint failed. Foreign key constraint `test/test` already exists on data dictionary. Foreign key constraint names need to be unique in database. Error in foreign key definition: CONSTRAINT `test` FOREIGN KEY (`b`) REFERENCES `test`.`t2` (`id`). |
| Error   | 1005 | Can't create table 'test.t2' (errno: 121)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+---------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Lo puse tal cual me comentaste y sigue arrojando el mismo error.  La verdad que no estoy pudiendo encontrar el error a simple vista :/

Comment: Ahi probe con la tabla presentacion, que es la otra tabla que tiene FK, con esa no hubo problema al ejecutarla, habiendo seguido tus consejos. Osea que la que esta tirando problemas es la tabla "ACTUA"

Comment: @Jatzu Prueba los comandos que te indiqué, justo después de intentar crear esa tabla, para que te muestre cuál es el problema

Comment: Ahi lo pude solucionar. Aparentemente el error estaba en que la tabla ACTOR no estaba creada (esto debido a que a que en la sintaxis de "foto" y "sexo" de esa tabla no estaba bien definida. Quitando esas 2 columnas para poder crear la tabla, cual seria la asignacion correcta para poder crear la tabla con todos los valores correctos?. Desde ya, muchisimas gracias, me ayudaste un monton